# Equivalence relation generated by the images of two functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have a silly doubt. Well, if $f,g: X \to Y$ are two functions, then we can consider the equivalence relation $\sim_{f,g}$ on $Y$ defined as the equivalence relation generated by the relation

$$
R:=\{(f(x),g(x)): \,\, x \in X\}
$$

What is exactly such a relation $\sim_{f,g}$? First, I pass to the symmetric extension adding the pairs $\{(g(x),f(x)): \,\, x \in X\}$. Next, can I write

$$
y \sim_{f,g} y' \iff y=y' \, \vee \, \exists x \in X \,\, s.t. \,\, y=f(x) \, and \, y'=g(x)
$$

Actually, $\sim_{f,g}$ must be the transitive closure of $R$, so it should be
$$
y \sim_{f,g} y' \iff \exists n \ge 0, y_0,\dots,y_n \in X \,\, s.t. \,\, y=y_0, \, y'=y_n \, and \, y_iRy_{i+1} \, \forall i=0,\dots,n-1
$$
(by abuse, I denote by $R$ the starting relation together with the symmetric and the reflexive parts).

Which of the two formulas is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your formulas are incorrect. For consider $X = \{0\}$, $Y = \{0, 1\}$, $f(0) = 0$, $g(0) = 1$.

Then clearly we see that $\sim_{f, g} = Y^2$.

But according to both of your statements, we should expect that $(1, 0) \notin \sim_{f, g}$.

Edit: the question has been edited, so my answer must also be edited.

If $R$ is any relation, the smallest transitive, reflexive relation containing $R$ is always $\{(a, b) | \exists n \geq 0, \exists x_0, ..., x_n (a = x_0 \land b = x_n \land \forall i (0 \leq i < n \implies x_i R x_{i + 1})\}$. So your second answer is now correct.

Comment: I edited the question before your answer

Comment: @TheWanderer I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Does your answer hold also for infinite sets? In my question, I have no assumed finitess (and indeed I usually work with infinite sets)

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes. It's an interesting fact that we can express the transitive closure (and many other kinds of inductive definitions over finite operations or rules) using natural numbers.